# Redirect to another URL without changing URL

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to point all the request on my subdomain `http://test.example.com` to `https://www.example.com/test-url-wordpress/` and I have written the following `.htaccess`

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/test-url-wordpress/ [NC,L]`

This results in rediection to the given page but I don't want to change URL. I have also tried the following solution but it gives me `500 Internal Server Error`

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/test-url-wordpress/ [P]

> Note: I want to show content from given URL in case of any request on
>   that subdomain. FYI, site on main domain is in wordpress that's why I
>   can't put relative URL like `../test-url-wordpress/` here and event
>   that didn't work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your web.config file -

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect test.example.com to www.example.com" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="test.example.com" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/test-url-wordpress/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Well! where did you find this question is for IIS.

Comment: Server is apache on linux not on `IIS`. And remeber my URL shouldn't change in browser. Would be great to know solution for that. Thanks